# Digital ocean domain always redirect to "/" page

Tags: nginx, redirect, dns, digital-ocean, aiohttp

I'm new at digitalocean, trying to deploy my aiohttp app. I have got a domain name and it's already set in digitalocean dns records.

So, in my backend I have a route "/persons", it's available to get it if I go "{row_ip}/persons", but if ill try to get it with domain name "{domain_name}/persons" it will always redirect me to "/" page ( and also make "/" request from backend). Any suggestions how to make available to get "{domain_name}/persons" with domain name? Thanks for your time.

Comment: DNS just resolves the domain name to your app's IP and so it's likely not the problem. What DNS record did you use? Can you resolve `${domain_name}` to the correct IP for your droplet? `nslookup ${domain_name}`? It may be that the domain has not propagated. Are you using TLS? If `nslookup` resolves correctly, can you try `curl --request GET http://${domain_name}/persons`? If you're using TLS then `https://`

Comment: nope, i can't request it, it's always redirect me to http://${domain_name} index page.
I also can find my a record in https://www.whatsmydns.net/

Answer (score 0):

The following works for me:

I created a basic Golang web server:

```
package main

import (
    "flag"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/http"
)

var (
    port = flag.Int("port", 0, "HTTP server port")
)

func hello(w http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "hello\n")
}

func main() {
    flag.Parse()

    http.HandleFunc("/x", hello)
    http.HandleFunc("/y", hello)

    log.Printf("Starting server: %d", *port)
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(fmt.Sprintf(":%d", *port), nil))
}
```

Build it:

```sh
go build -o server .
```

Create Droplet and grab its IP:

```sh
doctl compute droplet create ${INSTANCE} \
--region=${REGION} \
--size=${SIZE} \
--ssh-keys=${SSH_KEY} \
--image=${IMAGE}

IP=$(doctl compute droplet get ${INSTANCE} \
--format PublicIPv4 \
--no-header)
```

Update DNS:

```sh
doctl compute domain records create ${DOMAIN} \
--record-type=A \
--record-name=${INSTANCE} \
--record-data=${IP} \
--record-ttl=3600

nslookup ${INSTANCE}.${DOMAIN}
```

Copy the binary:

```sh
scp \
-i ${ID} \
${PWD}/server \
root@${INSTANCE}.${DOMAIN}:.
```

SSH in and start the server:

```sh
PORT="6666"
ssh \
-i ${ID} \
root@${INSTANCE}.${DOMAIN} \
./server --port=${PORT}
```

Then test it:

```sh
curl http://${INSTANCE}.${DOMAIN}:${PORT}/x
hello
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with a rewrite in an htaccess file in your website’s directory.

You will want to create an .htaccess file in that directory with the following (replacing the IP and domain with your own):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^12\.34\.56\.789$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domainname.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```